# Uneven spacing between subfigures on 2 different lines?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I'm trying to get 8 subfigures to stack on 2 lines so they match up vertically on the page. However, the top line seems evenly spaced across the page and the bottom line is evenly spaced but the gap is way smaller. I'm a bit new to tex so please go easy on me if my code is horrid.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.16\textheight]{Figures/Q1.png}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}
\caption[contents]{caption}
\label{fig:Qual}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I copy-pasted the code for each sf so I don't get why it would act differently on each line. All 8 images are identical resolution (1780x1752). Clearly I'm missing something simple...any help?

Comment: You're actually missing a closing `]` in the first `\subtop`...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: Ok code updated as instructed. I've compiled this and it gives me the same misaligned boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are wider then width of minipages. If you accommodate the width of images to width of minipages, than images are not overlapped anymore. See:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amsfonts} \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} \newsubfloat{figure} \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!] \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth} \centering
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
\end{minipage} \caption[contents]{caption} \label{fig:Qual}
\end{figure} \end{document}
```

In this case you can omit the minipages in put imagres directly into your figure. Something like this:

```
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}\hfill
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}\hfill
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}\hfill
\subtop[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\hsize]{example-image}\label{sf:Q1}}
```

With added \hfill after first three images I obtain wider gap between them.

Since I haven't your original images, I use example images. In figure below the first four images are generated by code without minipages and introduced \hfill between pictures.
[image]

**Edit:**
Of course, I manually divided images into two rows.